Firebase Cloud Messaging Legacy server key
As a device group, I did pushmessaging in the app. The document says to use an existing legacy api because api v1 does not support device group management. However, from today, the POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification endpoint suddenly started responding to a 401 error.
How can I solve this?
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification
Http Response code - 401 Unauthorized
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <!-- GSE Default Error -->
    <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
    <H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>

</HTML>

BUT, server key is valid

If you set the value of access_token_auth in the request header to true, then use Oauth token
